# John Hopkins ArcGIS coronavirus map by date?

Tags: arcgis

I'm sure we're all familiar with the excellent JHU global map they made showing the coronavirus cases (and other data):

https://www.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6

I was just wondering if anyone knows of a way to show the same visualization but as of a particular date?  Or does it always just show the latest results.

If the answer is "always the latest," I'd appreciate if anyone could point me to a few links to replicate the main map using their github data.

Answer (score 0):

The website says `Last Updated At` at bottom left corner. So it is always the latest.

The data they use [is in Github](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data)